# Check If value appears twice in array

Tags: arrays, vb.net, arraylist

I have and array and i want to check if my Dim value is contains in array but i need to check if it appears twice.

Example:

```
Dim value as String = "AST"

Dim zone_check_list() As String = {"AMST","AST","AST","EET","EDT"}

'if "AST" appeared twice then i will show message box
```

Comment: You should pass it through a loop..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How about using LINQ :

```
Imports System.Linq

Dim value as String = "AST"
Dim zone_check_list() As String = {"AMST","AST","AST","EET","EDT"}
Dim isAppearTwice As Boolean = (zone_check_list.Count(Function(x) x = value) = 2)
Console.WriteLine(isAppearTwice)
```